# How to retrieve a BigQuery table with 100+GB size to R

Tags: r, performance, google-bigquery

I currently have a table in BigQuery with a size of 100+GB that I would like to retrieve to R. I am using the `list_tabledata()` function in `bigrquery` package in R, but it takes a huge amount of time.

Anyone has recommendation on handling this large amount of data in R, and how to boost the performance? Like any packages, tools?

Comment: Do you have the ram to support the data? If no, I'd suggest reading it in pieces and doing the work required. What are you trying to do with the info anyway? That may help others help you out more.

Comment: I need to do some modeling in R with the data, which consists 500,000 observations (rows) with 4000 features (columns). The data is in Google BigQuery, now having trouble to load the data into R. Any ideas?

Comment: Yea I gathered that much, are you modelling using all 4000 features at once? If so, I'd argue you probably have to many variable and your model could be strengthened by using the most important variables. Perhaps bringing variables in, in batches to define the best model will help, 500,000 rows is not an issue for R, but 500,000 x 4000 can be a challenge (largely RAM dependant).

Comment: Yes, at some point I would need to delete many variables, but to figure out which variables to keep, I would still need to get all the data in and do some analysis, like PCA, right? Another way I can think of is to do some sampling, instead of the whole 500,000 obs. And which package you used for loading the data into R that gives good performance?

Comment: Could you export the BigQuery to CSV via its UI, and read it in that way?

Answer (score 1):

`tabledata.list` is not a great way to consume a large amount of table data from BigQuery - as you note, it's not very performant.  I'm not sure if bigrquery has support for table exports, but the best way to retrieve data from a large BigQuery table is using an export job.  This will dump the data to a file on Google Cloud Storage that you can then download to your desktop.  You can find more info on exporting tables in [our documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, would be: instead of bringing that large volume of data to code - try to bring your code to data. This can be challenging in terms of implementing logic in BQL. JS UDF might help. It depends.
In case if this is not doable - i would recommend either use sampled data or revisit your model